# Help with an integral involving zeta and digamma

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the integral:
$$f(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\tau-i\infty}^{\tau+i\infty}\frac{\zeta(z)}{z}\left[\psi\left(\frac{z}{s} \right ) +\frac{s}{2z}-\log\left(\frac{z}{s} \right )\right ]dz\;\;\;\;(\tau<0)$$
$\zeta(\cdot)$ being the Riemann zeta function, and $\psi\left(\cdot\right)$ being the Digamma function. We wish for an explicit evaluation of integral, possibly with a proof that $f(s)$ has an analytic continuation to the whole complex plane, except for a branch cut along the $s$ imaginary axis.

Comment: i don't see how this is a Mellin-type integral !

Comment: Sorry , that was a stupid suggest